# Does NAT in VirtualBox (Ubuntu guest) require connection sharing in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

Is "connnection sharing" necessary in windows-7 host to allow VirtualBox's Ubuntu guest connect to internet through (default) NAT interface?
My network administrator (on the machine at work) has disabled "conenction sharing" and some answers in threads( https://serverfault.com/questions/225155/virtualbox-how-to-set-up-networking-so-both-host-and-guest-can-access-internet) suggest it is necessary.

**Note**
It seems I face "proxy issues" in the cocorporation where I work. We are behind some kind of http proxy so my browser works but (probably) no other connections are allowed.

**Note2** Connection sharing has nothing to do with my problem. I solved it after investigating proxy settings: it turned out that I should set http_proxy environment variable on guest Ubuntu (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto) and my problem is immediately solved.

Comment: Are you experiencing a particular issue with VirtualBox networking or is this more of a curiosity / planning for the future sort of issue?

Comment: Issue: After installing ubuntu guest with default network connection settings (NAT) I still cannot connect internet from guest. Host uses (working) wireless. I want to upgrade guest and I'm not interested in connecting host<->guest for other purposes.

Comment: Could you please include the output of `ifconfig` from your Ubuntu guest in your original question?

Comment: ifconfig output: (.png link) https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1tQMEZ4XjQmTnVkRUhQZEdsSWM/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No. VirtualBox does not require the connection sharing feature of Windows to have NAT function properly.

The answer you have pointed to on serverfault.com is answering a more complex networking scenario where the guest requires additional network access beyond what NAT can easily provide.

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason why it would need that. And a test confirms this.

(Screenshot of virtual box and a freshly installed -5 min ago- VM, happily pinging a server on the internet. The host of the VM has internet sharing disabled).

[image]